# Spotfire IronPython script: Delete a data-table

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am new to iron-python. I would be obliged if anyone can tell me how to completely delete a data-table using iron-python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this pretty easily with:

```
dt_name = "Data Table" # name of the data table

dt = Document.Data.Tables[dt_name]

Document.Data.Tables.Remove(dt)
```

of course you can compress this all to:

```
Document.Data.Tables.Remove(Document.Data.Tables["Data Table"])
```